# Change the value in a cell every second

Tags: excel, vba, ontime

I have graphs that are updated based on the value in one cell. I am trying to write a script that changes the value in this cell every second and updates the graphs in the process.

The program does not wait one second to call the procedure and rather runs everything directly.

I tried other methods such as `Application.wait` which works in regards to waiting but it does not update the graphs.

Why doesn't `Application.OnTime` wait one second?

```vb
Sub graphOverTime()

Do While Range("N5").Value = "Running"
    
    'changes cell N5 to Not running on condition
    Call my_procedure

    'Update value in D3 that impacts the graphs
    current_month = Range("D3").Value

    Range("D3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(current_month, 1)
    
    DoEvents
    
    'Wait one second to rerun procedure
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"), "graphOverTime"
    
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is `Do While` looping which causes `Application.OnTime` to set overlapping scheduled calls of `graphOverTime`. Following is one way of doing what you wanted to in the first place

```
Sub graphOverTime()
    If Range("N5").Value = "Running" Then
        'changes cell N5 to Not running on condition
        Call my_procedure
    
        'Update value in D3 that impacts the graphs
        Range("D3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Range("D3").Value, 1)
        
        DoEvents
        
        'Wait one second to rerun procedure
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"), "graphOverTime", False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I was also skeptical to the while loop but I saw something similar worked for someone else so that is why I tried it. Thank you again! :D :D